# Docker-Selenium Maximum number of chrome containers

Tags: selenium, docker, protractor

I'm setting up a test infrastructure using **Azure & Docker - Selenium HUB and Chrome Images**

Running the latest version of Ubuntu on AZURE

*System Configuration*

Ubuntu:16*
Docker: Latest Version
RAM: 6GB
SSD: 120GB

Able to run automation script in the Chrome containers without any issue, if the number of containers is **<=10**.

When I scale up the numbers, entire system freezes and not responding and the tests are not running.

PS: I'm also mounting `/dev/shm:/dev/shm` when creating the containers.

What should be the optimal system configuration to run a minimum of 75 containers?

Comment: 75 containers in parallel? I'm the author of elgalu/docker-selenium and also co-author for https://github.com/zalando/zalenium so I have some experience with the tooling and I can assure you it makes total sense that the machine can't take more than 10. Diego and I will probably work on horizontal scalability next year but for now you can only scale vertically and adjust the instance size to your current load. I would distribute the load in separate grids on separate machines instead of trying to run them all 75 at the same time on the same instance, if possible.

Comment: @LeoGallucci Yes, 75 Containers in parallel. I thought running more containers on a single machine in parallel would reduce my test infrastructure cost. Maybe I was over ambitious :)  I'll try the approach that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

6GB RAM for 75 containers means ~ 80 MB/container. That too you want to run a firefox/chrome inside? Which may be running headless/without display but that doesn't mean they are not memory hungry.

You would need to park 500MB memory/container for such nodes. You can set a memory limit but as soon as your container goes above it, poof!!!. The container is dead and so is your browser and your test. Best is to either use Docker Swarm to deploy a self healing Selenium Grid

Or you can use https://github.com/zalando/zalenium as mentioned by @Leo Galluci.

PS: I wrote an article on how to setup Grid on swarm http://tarunlalwani.com/post/deploy-selenium-grid-using-docker-swarm-aws/. You can have a look at the same to get an idea at the horizontal scaling your grid